# Android Security Automatically lock

Tags: lock-screens, 5.0-lollipop, automation, smart-lock

I'm using a Moto X (2nd Gen.) with Android 5.0 and I'm trying to utilize Smart Lock by setting the option in Settings → Security → Automatically lock to:

> 5 seconds after sleep, except when kept unlocked by Smart Lock

No matter what I change it to, Android will still force me to enter my pattern, except when unlocked by Smart Lock (Trusted devices, Trusted places).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong. It's an intended feature. Why should your device be unlocked when you told it to lock after 5 seconds?

Comment: @GiantTree Hmm, Let's say I locked my phone by pressing `Power Button` and then remembered something (within 5 seconds) and when I turn it back on, `Android` asks me for my pattern, I thought feature would allow me to bypass entering pattern if phone is turned back on within time period specified (5 seconds) in this case.

Comment: Pressing the power button locks the device instantly. As by design/security reasons.